# How to auto adjust the width of a div when child element added

Tags: html, css

HTML

```
<div id="outer_div" style="overflow:auto; width:1238px; height:310px;">
 <div id="inner_div" style="height:300px;">
   <div id="child1" style="width:400px;">
   </div>
   <div id="child2" style="width:400px;">
   </div>
   <div id="child3" style="width:300px;">
   </div>
   <div id="child4" style="width:500px;">
   </div>
   <div id="child5" style="width:300px;">
   </div>
   <div id="child6" style="width:600px;">
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

What I want is the `inner_div`'s width should go beyond the `outer_div` and child divs will remain on same line. I am adding child divs into `inner_div` by using jquery prepend and append method. Currently the maximum width `inner_div` is taking the width of `outer_div` and after that the line breaks.

I tried with `display:inline-block`, `overflow:auto;` and `width:auto` on `inner_div` but its not working.

Currently I am getting it to work using jquery by adding width dynamically to `inner_div` as I am dynamically adding child divs into `inner_div`. I would like to achieve it using css if possible.

Comment: did you try adding overflow-x:visible to the outer -div?

Comment: @Anurag yes I tried with no luck

Answer (score 0):

Use `table` and `table-cell` properties to achieve this.

```
#inner_div{display:table;}
#inner_div div{display:table-cell;}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/5HCvj/1/)

Comment: The problem with table is that the inner div remains within the size of the outer div and child divs of inner div cannot retain their own width and adjusts to the width of inner div accordingly. In my case, I may need to add 100s of divs within the inner div with width of minimum 300 to 400px and I don't think its possible with table cell.

Comment: instead width you can use `min-width`. It will resolve this using table.

Answer (score 0):

you should use min-width on outer_div and float(or display:inline-block) on children of inner_div .
or use position absoulote on inner_div:

```
<div id="outer_div" style="min-width:1238px; height:310px">
 <div id="inner_div" style="height:300px;">
   <div id="child1" style="width:400px;display:inline-block">
   </div>
   <div id="child2" style="width:400px;display:inline-block">
   </div>
   <div id="child3" style="width:300px;display:inline-block">
   </div>
   <div id="child4" style="width:500px;display:inline-block">
   </div>
   <div id="child5" style="width:300px;display:inline-block">
   </div>
   <div id="child6" style="width:600px;display:inline-block">
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

or if you want fixed width of outer_div you can use position:

```
<div id="outer_div" style="width:1238px; height:310px;position:relative;white-space: nowrap;">
 <div id="inner_div" style="height:300px;position:absolute; top:0 ">
   <div id="child1" style="width:400px;display:inline-block">
   </div>
   <div id="child2" style="width:400px;display:inline-block">
   </div>
   <div id="child3" style="width:300px;display:inline-block">
   </div>
   <div id="child4" style="width:500px;display:inline-block">
   </div>
   <div id="child5" style="width:300px;display:inline-block">
   </div>
   <div id="child6" style="width:600px;display:inline-block">
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

by display table , inner_div can't get width larger than 1238!
also, I think , you can't add new element by css!

Comment: I need to use fixed width for outerdiv, so I tried with your second suggestion but no luck.

Comment: sorry I forgot this :  you must add **"white-space: nowrap;"** to outer_div